# How to use List.filter?

Tags: list, filter, sml

I have this code to filter list of string that the first letter is capital:

```
fun f s = Char.isUpper(String.sub(s,0));
fun only_capitals (xs : string list) =  List.filter(f , xs);
```

But when compile, I always receive error :

```
operator domain: 'Z -> bool
operand:         (string -> bool) * string list
  in expression:
    List.filter (f,xs)
```

What does this error mean? How to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be Dan Grossman's (Coursera/U Washington) Programming Languages assignment hw #3, problem #1.  "Write a function `only_capitals` that takes a string list and returns a string list that has only the strings in the argument that start with an uppercase letter. Assume all strings have at least 1 character. Use `List.filter`, `Char.isUpper`, and `String.sub` to make a 1-2 line solution."

Comment: It's probably worth referring to page 13 of Grossman's lecture notes leading to this assignment. "As an example, List.foldl((fn (x,y) => x+y),0,[3,4,5]) does not type-check because List.foldl expects 'a *  'b -> 'b function, not a triple. The correct call is List.foldl (fn (x,y) = x+y) 0 [3,4,5]..." It uses currying, is the thrust. This tripped me up for quite a while, too.

Comment: Powerful one liner: List.filter(fn x => Char.isUpper(String.sub(x, 0))) xs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type signature of [`List.filter`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html) is

```
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

So you need to give `List.filter` two distinct arguments, *not one argument which happens to be a tuple*.

Comment: As do must of the functions you'll come across in ML ;-)

Comment: @pad Correct me if I am wrong, it's not *two* arguments, just calling `List.filter` with first argument to get a function, and then calling _that returned_ function with the second argument, right?

Answer (score 8):

You need to change it to:

```
fun only_capitals (xs : string list) =  List.filter f xs
```

`filter` takes 2 arguments, a function `f` (`'a -> bool`) and a list.

It's easy to confuse syntax of passing a tuple in ML with the sytax of functional application in other languages.

You could also define it as:

```
val only_capitals = List.filter f
```

Comment: I believe a more appropriate wording would be that `filter` takes 1 argument (a function) and returns a function that takes a list.  Filter doesn't take 2 arguments.

From the docs:
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list

Answer (score 5):

Functions in ML can take only **one** argument. Description from [here](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/13wi/lec9slides.pdf) (see also notes and video there).

`List.filter` is so called curried function, so `List.filter f xs` is actually `(List.filter f) xs` where `List.filter f` is a function. We have to provide `f (fn: a -> bool)` as an argument to `List.filter`, not tuple `(f, xs)`.

Here is a simple example. When we call `is_sorted 1` we get a closure with `x` in its environment. When we call this closure with 2 we get `true` because `1 <= 2`.

```
val is_sorted = fn x => (fn y => x <= y)
val test0 = (is_sorted 1) 2

val is_sorted = fn : int -> int -> bool
val test0 = true : bool
```

Answer (score 3):

In the SML document, it states that:

filter f l
    applies f to each element x of l, from left to right, and returns the list of those x for which f x evaluated to true, in the same order as they occurred in the argument list.

So it is a curried function.

Answer (score 1):

In the SML document, the filter function in the `List` structure listed as

```
filter f l
```

where it takes curried arguments `f` and `l`

Instead of passing the arguments in a tuple, you have to provide a function and the list separated by spaces. The answer will be like this

```
fun only_capitals (xs: string list) = 
    List.filter (fn s => Char.isUpper(String.sub(s,0))) xs
```